# How can I remove a value from a drop down list based on a selection in another drop down list?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

To be more descript than the title, I have a series of drop down lists in asp.net that are all populated with the same values from the same procedure.  I am trying to figure out a way to remove values from subsequent drop down lists if that value has already been selected in a previous list.  For example, if a user selects "Value 1" in "ddl 1", "Value 1" should not appear in "ddl 2" or any other subsequent list (ddl 3, ddl 4, etc...)
Right now I have my lists being populated by the same procedure and I have another procedure that attempts to filter previously selected values.

Drop Down Lists:

```
<td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEquipmentType1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" Width="200px" />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" name="txtIndoorUnit1SerialNumber" Placeholder="Serial #" MaxLength="20" ID="txtIndoorUnit1SerialNumber" Style="width: 200px;" errorName="<%$ Resources:Locale, Global_IndoorUnit1SerialNumber%>" />
                    <span runat="server" id="vldReqIndoorUnit1SerialNumber" style="color: Red;" Visible="False">*</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="trIndoorUnit2SerialNumber" runat="server" visible="false">
                <td style="vertical-align:top">
                    <asp:label runat="server" id="Label30" Text="<%$ Resources:Locale, Global_IndoorUnit2SerialNumber%>" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEquipmentType2" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" Width="200px" />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" name="txtIndoorUnit2SerialNumber" Placeholder="Serial #" MaxLength="20" ID="txtIndoorUnit2SerialNumber" Style="width: 200px;" errorName="<%$ Resources:Locale, Global_IndoorUnit2SerialNumber%>" />
                    <span runat="server" id="vldReqIndoorUnit2SerialNumber" style="color: Red;" Visible="False">*</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

(There are more, but this is how they are all set up)

Population procedure:

```
Protected Sub PopEquipmentDDLs()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT RecID, EquipmentType FROM EquipmentTypes WHERE RecID IN (SELECT PrimaryEType FROM ETRelationship WHERE RecID = @RecID UNION ALL SELECT AccessoryEType1 FROM ETRelationship WHERE RecID = @RecID UNION ALL SELECT AccessoryEType2 FROM ETRelationship WHERE RecID = @RecID UNION ALL SELECT AccessoryEType3 FROM ETRelationship WHERE RecID = @RecID UNION ALL SELECT AccessoryEType4 FROM ETRelationship WHERE RecID = @RecID UNION ALL SELECT AccessoryEType5 FROM ETRelationship WHERE RecID = @RecID UNION ALL SELECT AccessoryEType6 FROM ETRelationship WHERE RecID = @RecID UNION ALL SELECT AccessoryEType7 FROM ETRelationship WHERE RecID = @RecID UNION ALL SELECT AccessoryEType8 FROM ETRelationship WHERE RecID = @RecID UNION ALL SELECT AccessoryEType9 FROM ETRelationship WHERE RecID = @RecID) AND EquipmentType <> @PEquipmentType"
    Dim ddlCollection As New List(Of DropDownList)() From {ddlEquipmentType1, ddlEquipmentType2, ddlEquipmentType3, ddlEquipmentType4, ddlEquipmentType5, ddlEquipmentType6, ddlEquipmentType7, ddlEquipmentType8, ddlEquipmentType9}
    Dim selectedValues As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)()

    'For i As Integer = 0 To ddlCollection.Count - 1
    '    Dim ddl As DropDownList = ddlCollection(i)
    '    If ddl.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
    '        selectedValues.Add(i, ddl.SelectedItem.Value)
    '    End If
    'Next

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WillisConnectionString").ToString)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("RecID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlNbZones.SelectedValue
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("PEquipmentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEType.Text
            conn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader())

            'Clear all drop-down lists
            For Each ddl As DropDownList In ddlCollection
                ddl.Items.Clear()
                ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem("---SELECT EQUIPMENT---", "0"))
            Next

            'populate drop-downs
            For i As Integer = 0 To ddlCollection.Count - 1
                Dim ddl As DropDownList = ddlCollection(i)

                ddl.DataSource = dt
                ddl.DataTextField = "EquipmentType"
                ddl.DataValueField = "RecID"
                ddl.DataBind()

                'If selectedValues.ContainsKey(i) Then
                '    ddl.SelectedValue = selectedValues(i)
                'End If
            Next

            For Each item In ddlEquipmentType2.Items
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item)
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Filter Procedure:

```
Private Sub FilterDDLs(ByVal ddlCollection As List(Of DropDownList))
    For i As Integer = 0 To ddlCollection.Count - 2
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = ddlCollection(i)

        ' Skip filtering if selected index is 0
        If ddl.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
            Dim selectedItemText As String = ddl.SelectedItem.Text

            For j As Integer = i + 1 To ddlCollection.Count - 1
                Dim subsequentDDL As DropDownList = ddlCollection(j)

                Dim itemToRemove As ListItem = subsequentDDL.Items.FindByText(selectedItemText)
                If itemToRemove IsNot Nothing Then
                    subsequentDDL.Items.Remove(itemToRemove)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I call the filter procedure from the databinding event of the drop down lists,  It loops through all the lists and attempts to remove items based on matching text I have also tried removing them based on selected value since they are all the same values.

If I remove the "If ddl.SelectedIndex > 0 Then" and don't look for ddls with an index greater than 0 it will remove the ListItem I am adding in the population procedure at value(0) but for whatever reason I cannot get it to remove values 1+.

I am unsure if I am calling this in the wrong place, but I've tried calling the filter procedure in the "selectedIndexChanged" event as well to no avail.

I have also tried filtering the lists in the population procedure and then calling the pop procedure in each "selectedIndexChanged" event instead of having a separate procedure for it. Hence the commented code that stores selected values in the dictionary and then reassigns them after the fact.

Any assistance regarding this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Think the issue is you're setting the data-source for your drop downs to a datatable  then attempting to directly manipulate the items collection.  IMO You would be better of either a) Filtering the datatable (Filtering as in hiding rows) or b) don't set the data source, instead add the items directly to the drop-down item collections.  Both options have their own complications but avoids the mish-mash of techniques

Comment: @Hursey, thanks for the reply. When you set the datasource of a drop down list to a data table, do the items in that list become immutable? does the data table persist after I call my population procedure or does it set the values of the ddl and then dispose of itself when the using block is exited?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking.  At the moment you DT object is scoped to the PopEquipmentDDLs sub.  You may have to move this up to the page if planning on filtering the data rather than items collection.  One thing to consider, you're using the same DataTable for all the dropdowns, might be a little unpredictable about what happens to previously selected dropdown value

Comment: Actually, I don't recommend you try and filter at the data table level - too much code. See the example below, it much less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so say this markup:

I am going to use a listbox, but the list box "event" model is 100% the same as a combo box (drop downlist), and this code can be quite much interchanged with a listbox or DropDownList.

so, the markup:

Let's drop 3 list box on the page.

Eg. this:

```
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"
            style="float:left"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"
            Height="220px" Width="230"
            AutoPostBack="true"
            SelectionMode="Multiple"
        >
        </asp:ListBox>


        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server"
            style="float:left;margin-left:20px"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged"
            Height="220px" Width="230"
            AutoPostBack="true"
            SelectionMode="Multiple"
        >
        </asp:ListBox>


        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox3" runat="server"
            style="float:left;margin-left:20px"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName" 
            Height="220px" Width="230"
            SelectionMode="Multiple"
        >
        </asp:ListBox>
```

Code to load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadCombo
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadCombo()

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"
    Dim rstHotels As DataTable
    rstHotels = MyRst(strSQL)

    ListBox1.DataSource = rstHotels
    ListBox1.DataBind()

    ListBox2.DataSource = rstHotels
    ListBox2.DataBind()

    ListBox3.DataSource = rstHotels
    ListBox3.DataBind()


End Sub
```

And the "cascade code - we only need this for lb1, and lb2.

So, this code:

```
Protected Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Cascade()

End Sub

Protected Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Cascade(2)
End Sub

Sub Cascade(Optional lbStart As Integer = 1)

    ' remove all/any selected in 1 from 2
    If lbStart < 2 Then
        ListBox2.Items.Clear()
        For Each LB1 As ListItem In ListBox1.Items
            If Not LB1.Selected Then
                Dim nItem As New ListItem(LB1.Text, LB1.Value)
                ListBox2.Items.Add(nItem)
            End If
        Next
    End If

    ' now remove any selected in 2 from 3

    ListBox3.Items.Clear()
    For Each LB2 As ListItem In ListBox2.Items
        If Not LB2.Selected Then
            Dim nItem As New ListItem(LB2.Text, LB2.Value)
            ListBox3.Items.Add(nItem)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

And we now see/get this:

[image]

Now, of course, I used a helper routine to load the sql (just returns a data table). This is from my global handy dandy helper routines. (and is not really important to the above code example, but I am including as a FYI

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function
```

## Edit: For the skeptics, above as dropdown list.

So, take the existing markup, change to dropdown list

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ListBox1" runat="server"
            style="float:left"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"
            Width="230"
            AutoPostBack="true"
        >
        </asp:DropDownList>


        <asp:DropDownList ID="ListBox2" runat="server"
            style="float:left;margin-left:20px"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged"
            Width="230"
            AutoPostBack="true"
        >
        </asp:DropDownList>


        <asp:DropDownList ID="ListBox3" runat="server"
            style="float:left;margin-left:20px"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName" 
            Width="230"
        >
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

So, codebehind now becomes this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadCombo
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadCombo()

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"
    Dim rstHotels As DataTable
    rstHotels = MyRst(strSQL)

    ListBox1.DataSource = rstHotels
    ListBox1.DataBind()
    ListBox1.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please Select"))

    'ListBox2.DataSource = rstHotels
    'ListBox2.DataBind()

    'ListBox3.DataSource = rstHotels
    'ListBox3.DataBind()


End Sub

Protected Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Cascade()
End Sub

Protected Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Cascade(2)
End Sub

Sub Cascade(Optional lbStart As Integer = 1)

    ' remove all/any selected in 1 from 2
    If lbStart < 2 Then
        ListBox2.Items.Clear()
        For Each LB1 As ListItem In ListBox1.Items
            If Not LB1.Selected Then
                Dim nItem As New ListItem(LB1.Text, LB1.Value)
                ListBox2.Items.Add(nItem)
            End If
        Next
    End If

    'Now remove any selected in 2 from 3

    ListBox3.Items.Clear()
    For Each LB2 As ListItem In ListBox2.Items
        If Not LB2.Selected Then
            Dim nItem As New ListItem(LB2.Text, LB2.Value)
            ListBox3.Items.Add(nItem)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

And now we see/get this:

[image]

Of course this begs the question why not use ONE listbox with selectmode="multiple".

The only real downside to a listbox, is often users will NOT know that you can hold down the CTRL key to select multiple items, and as such, this does require keyboard + mouse operations.

Comment: Hey @AlbertDKallal, Thank you so much for your response, this took care of exactly what I needed, I really appreciate the help. I can safely say I also use the tip about the "helper routine" in just about all my projects now. I hope you enjoy your day, thanks again.